# Hibernate: ¿como puedo hacer un update si por parámetro recibo el objeto completo?

Tags: hibernate

Primero muestro el fragmento de código y luego intento explicar:

```
public void update(int id, String name) {

    EntityManager manager = EM_FACTORY.createEntityManager();
    EntityTransaction transaction = null;
    try {
        transaction = manager.getTransaction();
        transaction.begin();
        Cuentas obj = manager.find(Cuentas.class, id);
        obj.setNombre(name);
        manager.persist(obj);
        transaction.commit();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        if (transaction != null) {
            transaction.rollback();
        }
        ex.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        manager.close();
    }
}
```

Naturalmente esta seria la forma de hacerle update a un objeto que ya existe en la base de datos, se lo pide a la bdd lo edita y luego lo devuelve.

```
    public void update(Cuentas cuenta) {

    EntityManager manager = EM_FACTORY.createEntityManager();
    EntityTransaction transaction = null;
    try {
        transaction = manager.getTransaction();
        transaction.begin();


        manager.persist(cuenta);
        transaction.commit();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        if (transaction != null) {
            transaction.rollback();
        }
        ex.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        manager.close();
    }
}
```

Ahora intentaré explicar: estoy utilizando MVC (modelo vista controlador), en la vista yo solicite las cuentas, entonces quiero modificar una en particular por cualquier razón, y este objeto modificado lo devuelvo al modelo (sigue teniendo el mismo id) para que haga su respectiva actualización en la bdd.

me parece tonto tener que hacer un manager.find para obtener el objeto, si ya el objeto existe y lo estoy devolviendo modificado desde la vista, igual después del *find* se esta haciendo un *persist* entonces ¿por que no puedo hacer un *persist* directo del objeto? el error que me devuelve el IDE (Eclipse) es el siguiente:

```
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.PersistentObjectException: detached entity passed to persist: com.bdcontabilidad.models.Cuentas
at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1763)
at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1677)
at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1683)
at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.persist(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1187)
at com.bdcontabilidad.models.CuentasDAO.update(CuentasDAO.java:68)
at com.bdcontabilidad.models.ModeloCD.update(ModeloCD.java:137)
at com.bdcontabilidad.cd.Programa.main(Programa.java:38)
```

Caused by: org.hibernate.PersistentObjectException: detached entity passed to persist: com.bdcontabilidad.models.Cuentas

En mi main estoy colocando de forma manual los datos para  hacer la prueba:

```
    Monedas moneda = new Monedas (1,"USD");
    Cuentas cuenta = new Cuentas (1,moneda,"jeje");
    modelo.update(cuenta);
```

Estaré eternamente agradecido si es posible darle respuesta a esta pregunta, Saludos :).

Answer (score 1):

Encontre la "**solución**", pues creo entender que sucede, cuando haces una **Transacción** tu estas abriendo algo que se llama **Contexto**, entonces todo lo que no llames con el **manager** (basado en mi codigo de arriba), esta ***fuera del Contexto*** de la **Transacción**, entonces al hacer ***manager.persist*** de un objeto que el manager **no ha manejado** ("no lo conoce", "no lo ha extraido él mismo de la bdd") lo rechaza, entonces existe el ***manager.merge*** que suple este problema, ¿de que forma lo hace? Pues merge hace una copia del objeto que esta recibiendo por parametro y lo añade al contexto de la transaccion y automáticamente lo persiste.

Código de la solución:

```
    public void update(Cuentas cuenta) {

    EntityManager manager = EM_FACTORY.createEntityManager();
    EntityTransaction transaction = null;
    try {
        transaction = manager.getTransaction();
        transaction.begin();
        manager.merge(cuenta);
        transaction.commit();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        if (transaction != null) {
            transaction.rollback();
        }
        ex.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        manager.close();
    }
}
```

Hice la prueba y reemplazó correctamente los datos de la cuenta en la bdd, ruego que corrijan mi respuesta si mi explicación no esta correcta.

Una cosa mas, este artículo me ayudo mucho a entender como solucionar este problema:

[Apúntes java: JPA: diferencia entre persist y merge](http://arisnegro.com.es/asn/blog/#!entryId=entry_002&language=es)

Saludos :).

Comment: No olvides marcar esta respuesta como solución aprobada con el boton en forma de V del lado izquierdo